# Unable to sort the data from whole table

Tags: jquery, sorting, pagination

If I set the `pagination` to `5` than I'm unbale to sort the data from all pages of the table in `ascending` or `descending` order from all pages, it will sort the data only from current page. I want to fix this whatever the `pagination` is, the data will `sorted` from all pages of table not only from `current page`. The [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/innoo_devil/3a0qb546/) of this is that.

Secondly, how to preset size of pagination to `5` or `10`.  Kindly help me out please.

**HTML FILE**

```
<div  style="margin-top:35px;">
        <h4>Per Page:</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="state" id="maxRows" class="form-control" style="width: 150px;">
            <option value="500">Pagination</option> 
            <option value="5">5</option>    
            <option value="10">10</option>  
            <option value="15">15</option>  
            <option value="20">20</option>  
            <option value="50">50</option>  
            <option value="100">100</option>
            <option value="100">500</option>
            <option value="100">1000</option>       
            </select>
          </div>

<table id="mytable" class="table table-hover table-bordered results">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">Name</th>
      <th class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">Qty</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="my" data-link="row" class="rowlink">
  <tr><td>1</td><td>A</td><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>B</td><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>C</td><td>12</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>D</td><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td><td>E</td><td>15</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td><td>F</td><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td><td>G</td><td>30</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td><td>H</td><td>50</td></tr>
  <tr><td>9</td><td>I</td><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr><td>10</td><td>J</td><td>90</td></tr>
  <tr><td>11</td><td>K</td><td>20</td></tr>
  <tr><td>12</td><td>L</td><td>10</td></tr>

        <tbody>

        </tbody>
</table>
    <div class="pagination-container col-md-6">
        <nav>
            <ul class="pagination"></ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
    //for pagination


    var table = '#mytable'
    $('#maxRows').on('change', function(){
        $('.pagination').html('')
        var trnum = 0
        var maxRows = parseInt($(this).val())
        var totalRows = $(table+' tbody tr').length
        $(table+' tr:gt(0)').each(function(){
            trnum++
            if(trnum > maxRows){
                $(this).hide()
            }
            if(trnum <= maxRows){
                $(this).show()
            }
        })
        if(totalRows > maxRows){
            var pagenum = Math.ceil(totalRows/maxRows)
            for(var i=1;i<=pagenum;){
                $('.pagination').append('<li data-page="'+i+'">\<span>'+ i++ +'<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>\</li>').show()
            }
        }
        $('.pagination li:first-child').addClass('active')
                $('.pagination li').on('click',function(){
                var pagenum = $(this).attr('data-page')
                var trIndex = 0;
                    $('.pagination li').removeClass('active')
                    $(this).addClass('active')
                    $(table+' tr:gt(0)').each(function(){
                    trIndex++
                    if(trIndex > (maxRows*pagenum) || trIndex <= ((maxRows*pagenum)-maxRows)){
                        $(this).hide()
                    }else{
                        $(this).show()
                    }
                    })
                })                              
    });

    //for sorting per page

$(document).ready(function() {


  $("th").click(function() {
    sortTable($("#mytable"), $(this));
  });


});


function sortTable(table, th) {
    var rows = $(table).find("tr:gt(0)").toArray().sort(compare($(th).index()));

    if ($(th).hasClass("ascending")) {
      $(th).removeClass("ascending").addClass("descending");
      rows = rows.reverse();
    }
    else {
      $(th).removeClass("descending").addClass("ascending");
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        $(table).append(rows[i]);
    }

    evenify($(table).attr("id"));
}

function compare(index) {
    return function(a, b) {
        var valA = $(a).children("td").eq(index).html();
        var valB = $(b).children("td").eq(index).html();
        return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB);
    }
}
```

My required result on clicking `Qty` image is attached below

[image: Required Result]

My current result on clicking `Qty` image is attached below

[image: Current Result]

Answer (score 0):

Use https://datatables.net/, do not invent a wheel this time.

Comment: Thanks , but i want to fix this code... can you help me for that?

Comment: ok, but you have trivial errors that pollute console can you fix them first?

Comment: ok, I figure it out. Your pagination is bases on hiding staff, and your sorting sorts everything, but hidden staff stays hidden. That is your problem. You sort everything all right, but you can only see what you saw before sorting. You need to show and hide things after sorting same way you do in on pagination. Is it clear?

Comment: yes it is , one thing i want to confirm , my pagination bases is good or not ?

Comment: well... Your approach is outdated. 10 years ago it would be good, but now, you better use a framework. Knockout.js would be the easiest to learn, but Vue2.js is my favorite.

Comment: Abstract functionality of pagination and sorting into functions and call them both every time you change pagination or sorting. Abstraction is you focus at this point.